# wrong images in listview because imageview is recycled

Tags: android-listview, picasso, android-async-http

The code looks like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Contact currContact = getItem(position);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder.profileIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileIV);
        viewHolder.nameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
**************************PER JAKE WHARTON's RESPONSE******************************************
        Picasso.with(getContext()).cancelRequest(viewHolder.profileIV);
    }

    String currName = currContact.getName();

    /* 1 
       Asynchronously GETs https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images? 
       rsz=8&start=0&v=1.0&imgsz=medium&imgtype=linear&q=(currName) */
    APIclient.getImageJson(getContext(), currName, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject imgJson) {
            try {
                JSONObject responseDataValue = imgJson.getJSONObject("responseData");
                JSONArray resultsValue = responseDataValue.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject result = resultsValue.getJSONObject(0);
                String imgUrl = result.getString("url");

                // 2
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imgUrl).into(viewHolder.profileIV);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

1. The asynchronous call is launched, and the user scrolls down.
2. The call completes, the image url is obtained, and Picasso makes ANOTHER GET request to render the image, but in the wrong imageview because of recycling

The only way I know to get around this is to make the first GET request(to obtain the image link) SYNCHRONOUS, blocking the ui to make sure getView isn't called again before the image is loaded.  Is there a better way to get around this?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Picasso does not have this behavior. When it sees the same `viewHolder.thumbnail` come back around from being recycled it will prevent the original request from setting the image. Show more code.

Comment: scrolling shows images in the wrong rows(from a previous visible row).  when I stop the image does not correct itself.  Sometimes scrolling will even make certain images just disappear forever.  The code that exhibits this behavior is shown in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is that you are only calling the `Picasso` object after making another asynchronous request. This means that Picasso has no way of knowing that the view was recycled for a new item.

The easiest way to solve this is by adding a call to Picasso to cancel existing requests for the recycled view.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).cancelRequest(viewHolder.profileIV)
```

This should be done **outside** of the `APIclient.getImageJson` call so that it runs synchronously when the adapter is called.

Comment: I added that line(please see original post), and it works if I scroll slowly, but not quickly.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: I have this exact same problem but I am using an AsyncTask to set up the bitmap thumbnail, and a view holder to recycle views.  the ListView briefly shows a previous from another item when scrolling through view before AsyncTask updates it correctly.  Thoughts?

Comment: i got the exact same problem. it shows the wrong image. how can we speed this up or fix it?